# Change format of NodeJs server console logs

Tags: node.js, debugging, express, logging

I'm using ExpressJs. The server logs the requests in the console and it looks like this :

[image]

Is there anyway I can

- Change the format of the logs?
- Add the request's IP address?
- Or simply disable it so I can make my own logs with my own listener?

I've been looking around for a while now, but can't seem to figure it out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the format by specifying it this way .

```
app.use(morgan(':method :url :status :response-time ms - :res[content-length] '));
```

you can change it to

```
app.use(morgan(':remote-addr :method :url :status :response-time ms - :res[content-length] '));
```

so now it will print remote address first then it will go on. you can change the order to get desired logs. 
(https://github.com/expressjs/morgan) . please read out the documentation for Predefined Formats ,

also you can remove 
`app.use(morgan('dev'));` 
to just get rid off the logs from the console.

Answer (score 0):

Express logging is just a middleware plugin. As long as you follow the same interface, you can replace it with anything you want.

See [express.logging](https://github.com/telefonica/node-express-logging) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Comment `app.use(logger('dev'));` from app.js file, for